# Video (.mp4) not getting downloaded in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, video

In my view i have a link to download a .mp4 like below

```
<a href="@Href("~/Content/mm/Manual_Video.mp4")" target="_blank"> Download Video </a>
```

and i stored the Manual_Video.mp4 in Content folder but when I click on the link I am getting below error

> 404 - File or directory not found. The resource you are looking for
>   might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily
>   unavailable.

Any idea?

**Edit**

Download PDF

this link is working fine.

Comment: Do you have in your RouteConfig line like `routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*pathInfo}");`? Could be that it's wrong routing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I check around and find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20232777/1849444):

Add a `MIME` type with extension mp4 in IIS

But please note that you should set the MIME type `video/mp4` instead of `video/mpeg` orelse in IE "Save Target As.." shows different format, and it also affects the default video player open by browser.

> video/mpeg
>
> File name: test.mpeg
>
> Save as type: Movie Clip
>
> video/mp4
>
> File name: test.mp4
>
> Save as type: MP4 Video

Comment: thanks for the answer but the same code for downloading a .pdf is working fine i tried ur Content and its giving the same error
`<a href="@Href("~/Content/mm/Guide.pdf")" target="_blank"> Download PDF </a>` this is working fine. so i dont think issue in routing

Comment: @Sachu i suppose problem is in IIS MIME types then.